# causal mediation packages with multiple mediators

Tags: r, causality

I am new to R, so I apologise for any obvious errors in my post below. I'm looking to undertake some causal mediation analyses and have been looking at the package mediation. In my data I have more than one mediator I wish to fit simultaneously, and some of the mediators are causally related. Is it possible to fit this type of model in this package (or another package)?

I have used the Stata macro gformula (which can estimate causal effects using g-computaton) elsewhere, although it does not seem to be able to deal with count outcomes, hence my query. Thanks for any pointers you may have.